# Something in my preamble breaks this tikz newcommand but only when used inside a foreach?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, macros, pgfmath

In a standalone document which I use to tinker with Tikz pictures before compiling in my main document as a way of saving compile time, I have used the following expression

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections,arrows.meta}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usepackage{pgfmath}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{declare function={randomfixed(\a,\b) = int(random(0,int(\b-\a))+\a);}}
\newcommand\randomint[2]{\bgroup%
  \pgfmathsetmacro\myval{randomfixed(#1,#2)}%
  \myval\egroup%
}

\foreach \i in {0,0.5,1,1.5,2}
  \draw (\i, 0) -- (\i, -1.5);
  
\foreach \i in {0,0.5,1,1.5}
  \draw (0,-\i) -- (2, -\i);

\foreach \i in {0.25, 0.75, 1.25, 1.75}
  \foreach \j in {-0.25, -0.75, -1.25}{
    \node[align=center] at (\i, \j) {\randomint{-1}{1}};
    }
    
\node[align=center] at (1, -2) {$A$};
\node[align=center] at (2.5, -2) {$*$};
\node[align=center] at (3.5, -2) {$B$};
\node[align=center] at (5.75, -2) {$A*B$};
\foreach \i in {3,3.5,4}
  \draw (\i, -0.25) -- (\i, -1.25);
\foreach \i in {-0.25, -0.75, -1.25}
  \draw (3,\i) -- (4, \i);
\foreach \i in {3.25,3.75}
  \foreach \j in {-0.5, -1}
    \node[align=center] at (\i, \j) {\randomint{-1}{1}};

\foreach \i in {3,4}
  \foreach \j in {-0.25, -1.25}
    \draw[blue] (\i, \j) -- (\i-2.5,\j-0.25);
  
\draw [fill=blue, opacity=0.2, draw=blue] (0.5,-0.5) rectangle (1.5,-1.5);

\foreach \i in {5, 5.5, 6, 6.5}
  \draw (\i, -0.5) -- (\i, -1.5);
\foreach \i in {-0.5, -1, -1.5}
  \draw (5, \i) -- (6.5, \i);

\draw[red] (3, -0.25) -- (5.5,-1);
\draw[red] (3, -1.25) -- (5.5,-1.5);
\draw[red] (4, -0.25) -- (6,-1);
\draw[red] (4, -1.25) -- (6,-1.5);

\draw [fill=red, opacity=0.2, draw=red] (5.5,-1) rectangle (6,-1.5);

\node[align=center] at (5.25, -0.75) {-1};
\node[align=center] at (5.75, -0.75) {1};
\node[align=center] at (6.25, -0.75) {-2};
\node[align=center] at (5.25, -1.25) {-2};
\node[align=center] at (5.75, -1.25) {0};
\node[align=center] at (6.25, -1.25) {1};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

to successfully define my image exactly the way I want it. However when I try and run the same code in my main document I am met with the following error messages:

Illegal parameter number in definition of \pgfmath@expression.

Illegal parameter number in definition of \pgfmath@bgroup@strip@last.

Illegal parameter number in definition of \pgfmath@next.

Illegal parameter number in definition of \pgfmath@bgroup@stripped.

Illegal parameter number in definition of \pgfmath@token.

Package PGF Math Error: Unknown operator `##' or` ##1' (in 'randomfixed(##1,##2)').

Illegal parameter number in definition of \pgfmath@bgroup@strip@last.

==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

However I am naturally confused given that this code compiles with no issue in the above example. I hence deduced there was a problem with my preamble and to confirm found that the code again compiled without issue in a document with the following preamble

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections,arrows.meta}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usepackage{pgfmath}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
.....
```

and the issue was replicated when I used the preamble from my main document of:

```
\documentclass[11pt, openany]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amsfonts}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\itshape \nouppercase \rightmark}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\itshape \nouppercase Chapter \arabic{chapter}}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections,arrows.meta}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfmath}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=tikz/]
\usepackage{comment}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=black
}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{lightgreen}{rgb}{0.56, 0.93, 0.56}
\definecolor{darkseagreen}{rgb}{0.56, 0.74, 0.56}
\definecolor{indianred}{rgb}{0.8, 0.36, 0.36}
\definecolor{airforceblue}{rgb}{0.36, 0.54, 0.66}
\definecolor{LightGray}{gray}{0.9}
\definecolor{amber}{rgb}{1.0, 0.75, 0.0}
\usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex}
\bibliography{refs}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{booktabs}



\makeatletter

% define a macro \Autoref to allow multiple references to be passed to \autoref
\newcommand\Autoref[1]{\@first@ref#1,@}
\def\@throw@dot#1.#2@{#1}% discard everything after the dot
\def\@set@refname#1{%    % set \@refname to autoefname+s using \getrefbykeydefault
    \edef\@tmp{\getrefbykeydefault{#1}{anchor}{}}%
    \xdef\@tmp{\expandafter\@throw@dot\@tmp.@}%
    \ltx@IfUndefined{\@tmp autorefnameplural}%
         {\def\@refname{\@nameuse{\@tmp autorefname}s}}%
         {\def\@refname{\@nameuse{\@tmp autorefnameplural}}}%
}
\def\@first@ref#1,#2{%
  \ifx#2@\autoref{#1}\let\@nextref\@gobble% only one ref, revert to normal \autoref
  \else%
    \@set@refname{#1}%  set \@refname to autoref name
    \@refname~\ref{#1}% add autoefname and first reference
    \let\@nextref\@next@ref% push processing to \@next@ref
  \fi%
  \@nextref#2%
}
\def\@next@ref#1,#2{%
   \ifx#2@ and~\ref{#1}\let\@nextref\@gobble% at end: print and+\ref and stop
   \else, \ref{#1}% print  ,+\ref and continue
   \fi%
   \@nextref#2%
}

\makeatother

\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}
```

So evidently the issue is with something in this preamble, finally the errors and issue do not happen if the \randomint function is called outside of a \foreach loop in the main document.

If anyone could help me diagnose the root of the issue that would be very helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, welcome! You're very near to finding the culprit. Start with your whole preamble and the first example so that the document fails, and then start removing things from your preamble until the document compiles again: now you have the culprit. Then post that as a minimal example of the failure, if you do not understand why it fails.

Comment: Thanks @Rmano, in the end as I was short for time I simply compiled my figures in a standalone document then included the PDFs as graphics.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem with the given preamble. By the way, you could define `\randomint` as `\newcommand*\randomint[2]{\pgfmathprint{randomfixed(#1,#2)}}`. `random(#1,#2)` would work, too. Your `randomfixed` function is the same as `random`.